# input file - показываем только файлы определенного типа

Tags: html

Как то сталкивался с такой фичей: инпут типа файл, при выборе файла с компьютера для загрузки показывается только определенный тип файлов (например, картинки jpg jpeg и пр.) 
Реализуемо ли такое средствами html или только flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/accept) можно почитать...

```
<input type="file" accept="MIME-тип">
```

> Устанавливает фильтр на типы файлов,
> которые вы можете отправить через поле
> загрузки файлов. Тип файла указывается
> как MIME-тип, при нескольких значениях
> они перечисляются через запятую. Если
> файл не подходит под установленный
> фильтр, он не показывается в окне
> выбора файлов.

Вообще - можно через JS попробовать ( но немного не то )

Comment: добавил >accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" но без толку, - видно все файлы.

Comment: В Chrome 15 - работает

Comment: FF последний - не работает, в опере да.

Comment: Firefox 4 поддерживает только значения audio/*, video/* и image/*.

разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В html-е у input'а есть такая опция - accept, но она работает [не во всех браузерах](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/accept). Поэтому надо использовать flash или java.