# Диалоговое окно выбора файла

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать диалоговаое окно выбора файла (с тем расширением которое указано)? Т.е. чтобы при нажатии на кнопку всплывало окно, в котором пользователь выберет файл для загрузки.

И как ещё сделать, чтобы, после выбора .txt файла, текст из него выводился в тег `p`?

Comment: https://webref.ru/html/input/accept

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [input file - показываем только файлы определенного типа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63119/input-file-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0)

Comment: @Visman accept - не единственное, что требуется ТС'у, поэтому ваша ссылка не совсем соответствует данному вопросу.

Comment: @Cheg, у TC два вопроса, а тут задают по одному вопросу за раз.

Comment: Автор, вы что не помните что писали в вопросе? 1 вопрос `Как сделать диалоговаое окно выбора файла (с тем расширением которое указано)?` 2 вопрос `И как ещё сделать, чтобы, после выбора .txt файла, текст из него выводился в тег p?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фильтрации загружаемых файлов по определенному расширению используйте атрибут [accept](https://webref.ru/html/input/accept).

Код вывода имени файла взят с [codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) и немного изменен под вопрос.

```js
'use strict';
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  $('.upload input[type="file"]').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this),
      $label = $input.closest('.upload');

    $input.on('change', function(e) {
      var fileName = '';

      if (this.files && this.files.length > 1)
        fileName = (this.getAttribute('data-multiple-caption') || '').replace('{count}', this.files.length);
      else if (e.target.value)
        fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();

      if (fileName)
        $label.find('p').html(fileName);
      else
        $label.find('p').html('');
    });

  });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="upload">
  <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" />
  <p class="filename"></p>
</label>

<label class="upload">
  <input type="file" data-multiple-caption="Файлов выбрано: {count}" multiple accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" />
  <p class="filename"></p>
</label>
```